# Proper pattern to handle one-to-many with different related entities

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a C# project and I use Entity Framework as the ORM. I have a `User`, which is able to pay to many banks. Each bank is a separate entity and each one of them is described by different fields.

The problem is - one `User` can have no-or-many different `Bank`s. I'm not really sure how to model this - the temporary solution was to add an additional `UserBank` entity, which is in 1:1 realtionship with `User`. The classes look (more or less) like that:

```
public class User
{
  public virtual UserBank Banks { get; set; }
  // (...)
}
```

and

```
public class UserBank
{
  public virtual User { get; set; }
  public virtual Bank1 { get; set; }
  public virtual Bank2 { get; set; }
  public virtual Bank3 { get; set; }
}
```

In that scenario, `User` may or may not have accounts in any of the `Bank`s. If he doesn't have one, the value will be `NULL`.

It's not perfect - but at least `User` doesn't need to know anything about `Bank` types. The problem is that if I want to add a new `Bank`, I need to modify `UserBank` entity, which is violating the `O` in `SOLID`, which I try to always follow.

Additionally, I don't like the idea that `UserBank` has to store N empty (NULL) columns for N banks if `User` doesn't have any bank accounts. Is there a proper pattern to handle that situation?

---

**EDIT**

I am aware that it's a relatively easy problem in raw SQL. The problem here is how to do that with Entity Framework with code-first.

Comment: Whenever you have the feeling, you should have indexed columns (Bank1, Bank2, Bank3 ...) this is **a lighting bright indication for the need of a related side table**...

Comment: @Shnugo can you please elaborate? The main problem is how to handle it in code-first Entity Framework - I know that it looks easy in a raw SQL, but I have no idea how to write it with EF

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classical `m:n` relationship. Each User can have different banks and each bank will have many users.

You need three tables:

- User (UserID, Name, ...)
- Bank (BankID, Name, ...)
- UserBank(UserBankID, UserID FK-to-User, BankID FK-to-Bank, FurtherDetails ...)

If you want to ensure, that a user cannot have multiple connections with the same bank, you might place a unique key on the combination of UserID/BankID or let this be the PK of you mapping table. But I don't think this was correct actually...

The entity tables (User/Bank) hold a description of *their* object, but nothing more. The mapping table gets all the needed data which describes the connection between these two (date of creation, active, account (which should be a FK to another entity table) and so on...)

### UPDATE example to illustrate a `m:n`-relationship

User

```
  1 John
  2 Jane
  3 Tim
```

Bank

```
 1 Bank of England
 2 Deutsche Bank
 3 Crash & Desaster
```

UserBank

```
 1 1 1 --> User 1 is connected with Bank 1 --> John uses BoE  
 2 1 2 --> John uses Deutsche Bank too  
 3 2 1 --> And Jane is at Deutsche Bank  
 4 3 3 --> while Tim is at C&D
```

### UPDATE 2

No experience with EF code first, but this would be the line in C#:

```
public class User
{
  public int UserID{get;set}
  public string Name...
  public List<UserBank> MyBanks{ ... fetch by this.UserID ... }
}
public class Bank
{
  public int BankID{get;set}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public List<UserBank> MyUsers{... fetch by this.BankID ... }
}

public class UserBank
{
  public int UserBankID{get;set}
  public User{get;set;}
  public Bank{get;set;} 
}
```

Comment: That unfortunately misses the main problem - there are many DIFFERENT banks, and each of them is a completely different entity. A single UserBank has to work with many banks and the main problem is handling that.

Comment: @KamilT No, I think you've got this wrong. Please see my update

Comment: Ok, now I see you point. But there's still a problem :) I use Entity Framework and Code-First, which is forcing constraints. In other words - UserBank needs to know what concrete `Bank` entity is needed - I can't have `BankID FK-to-Bank` like you suggested, I need to have an id of a concrete Bank

Comment: @KamilT, I'm not familiar with *EF-code-first*. Please avoid chameleon questions... StackOverflow is not only a site to get help, but also a huge archive of answered questions. Therefore the principle: One issue - one question. The initial question was about the *proper pattern*. I think this is solved... If so, please accept my answer to mark it as solved. Than start a new question for the new problem (*How do I set up a `m:n`-relationship with EF and code-first?*).

Comment: OK, I understand you, but "I have a C# project and I use Entity Framework as the ORM." is literally the first sentence in my question.

Comment: @KamilT People search for the title... Anyway, I just placed an UPDATE 2, might be a hint...