# A simplified version of Twitter. Understanding many-to-many relationships between tables in the database

Tags: sql, database-design

I am reading [this article about a Twitter-like application.](https://www.hiredintech.com/classrooms/system-design/lesson/67) The type of storage where tweets, users, likes, etc. will be stored is a relational database. The database scheme is described [here](https://www.hiredintech.com/classrooms/system-design/lesson/70) and drawn [here.](https://www.hiredintech.com/classrooms/system-design/lesson/72)

As an Android developer, I coded my sample using SQLite. This is how I would code it:

```
create table users (_id integer primary key, username text unique, first_name text, last_name text);
create table tweets (_id integer primary key, content text, created_at integer, user_id integer, foreign key(user_id) references users(_id));
create table connections (_id integer primary key, follower_id integer, followee_id integer, created_at integer, foreign key(follower_id) references users(_id), foreign key (followee_id) references users(_id));
create table favorites (_id integer primary key, user_id integer, tweet_id integer, foreign key (user_id) references users(_id), foreign key (tweet_id) references tweets(_id));
```

Now let's insert some data.

users:

```
insert into users values (1, 'user1', 'Lorem', 'Ipsum');
insert into users values (2, 'user2', 'Dolor', 'Sit');
insert into users values (3, 'user3', 'Foo', 'Bar');
insert into users values (4, 'user4', 'Qwerty', 'Trewq');
```

some tweets:

```
insert into tweets values(10, '1 Tweet from user1', 1100, 1);
insert into tweets values(11, '2 Tweet from user1', 1101, 1);
insert into tweets values(12, '3 Tweet from user1', 1102, 1);
insert into tweets values(13, '4 Tweet from user1', 1103, 1);

insert into tweets values(14, '1 Tweet from user2', 1103, 2);
insert into tweets values(15, '2 Tweet from user2', 1103, 2);

insert into tweets values(16, '1 Tweet from user3', 1103, 3);
insert into tweets values(17, '2 Tweet from user3', 1103, 3);

insert into tweets values(18, '1 Tweet from user4', 1107, 4);
```

favorites (the same as likes):

```
insert into favorites values(1, 2, 11);
insert into favorites values(2, 3, 13);
insert into favorites values(3, 4, 15);
```

There is a question about the database scheme:

> Do you think you could support with our database design the ability
>   to display a page for a given user with their latest tweets that were
>   favorited at least once?

Yes, this is why query:

```
sqlite> select favorites._id, tweets._id as tweet_row_id, tweets.content from favorites join tweets on tweets.user_id=1 and tweets._id = favorites.tweet_id order by tweets._id desc limit 1;
_id         tweet_row_id  content
----------  ------------  ------------------
2           13            4 Tweet from user1
```

Explanation:

The left dataset is the table *favorites*. The right dataset is the table *tweets*. I join the two datasets. Then `tweets.user_id=1 and tweets._id = favorites.tweet_id` is evaluated for each row of the resulting dataset as a boolean expression. If the result is true, the row is included. `order by tweets._id desc` is used to get the latest tweets (the greater `tweets._id` is, the newer the tweet is). `limit` is used to limit the number of rows. If the user has been using our Twitter-like app for years, we'll show the latest 10 or 20 tweets.

---

**My questions.**

1. Is there anything wrong with my database scheme? I omitted `not null`, `unique`, and other column constraints for simplicity.
2. [Here](https://www.hiredintech.com/classrooms/system-design/lesson/70) the author of the original article says:

> The first relation is addressed by sticking the user ID to each tweet.
>   This is possible because each tweet is created by exactly one user.
>   It’s a bit more complicated when it comes to following users and
>   favoriting tweets. The relationship there is many-to-many.

"The first relation" is users-tweets.

Why do we need a many-to-many here? In my scheme I only use a one-to-many.

**Update 1**

[image: Database Schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly I [placed an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41759965/5089204), where the OP - like you in this question - was unsure about `1:n` and `n:m`.

I assume, that your final sentence is the actual question you have:

> Why do we need a many-to-many here? In my scheme I only use a one-to-many

The relation user-tweets is `1:n`...

Think in objects

- user (id, name, ...)
- tweet (id, author (FK on user), datetime, content, ...)

The **like is an object** with sepecific details on its own:

- like (id, userid,tweetid,datetime,...)

For this you need a *mapping table* (you call it *favourites*)

There is a `1:n`-relation from users to this mapping and a `1:n`-relation from tweets to this mapping.
**These two `1:n`-relations form the `m:n`-relation together.**

Now each tweet can be liked by many users and each user can like many tweets, but one user should (probably) not like the same tweet twice (unique key or even a two column PK?). And you might introduce a `CHECK` constraint to ensure, that the liking user and the author's userid is not the same (don't like your own tweets).

### As a side note:

> Is there anything wrong with my database scheme

You should never create constraints wihtout naming them

```
CREATE TABLE Dummy
(
 ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Dummy PRIMARY KEY
,UserID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Dummy_UserID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User(id)
,...
)
```

If this database was ever installed on different systems, they'll get different (random) names and future upgrade scripts will get you in deepest pain...

### UPDATE: example for the side note

In you comment you ask, what this last sentence is about... Try this

```
CREATE DATABASE testDB;
GO
USE testDB;
GO
CREATE TABLE testTbl1(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,SomeValue INT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE testTbl2(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,FKtoTbl1 INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES testTbl1(ID));
GO
CREATE TABLE testTbl3(ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_3 PRIMARY KEY,SomeValue INT CONSTRAINT UQ_3_SomeValue UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE testTbl4(ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_4 PRIMARY KEY,FKtoTbl3 INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_4_FKtoTbl3 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES testTbl3(ID));

GO
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS;
GO
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE testDB;
GO
```

On column in your result looks like this:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
PK__testTbl1__3214EC27ABEA2C0C
UQ__testTbl1__0E5C381C04C8AF66
PK__testTbl2__3214EC272784631C
FK__testTbl2__FKtoTb__1367E606
PK_3
UQ_3_SomeValue
PK_4
FK_4_FKtoTbl3
```

If this script is run twice, the given names will stay as **you** defined them. The other names will get a random name like `PK__testTbl1__3214EC27ABEA2C0C`. Now imagine, you need to create an upgrade script for several installed systems where one constraint has to be dropped or modified. How would you do this, if you do not know its name?

Comment: `If this database was ever installed on different systems, they'll get different (random) names and future upgrade scripts will get you in deepest pain...` I didn't understand this part

Comment: `These two 1:n-relations form the m:n-relation together` I'm not sure I understand this part. When one author writes many books, and the same book can be written by a few authors, there is a many-to-many relationship between the two entities (represented by tables): authors and books. But as to my example, which entities have the many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev To modell a `m:n`-relation you need a table in the middle. In your example this is `AuthorBook` with a FK to Author and a FK to Book. Simple case 1 book 1 autor is one row. 1 autor many books is one row for each book, all with the same autor, many autors 1 book as before but vice-versa and m:n is a mixture of both...

Comment: By "my example" I meant the Twitter example from the question

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev It's not that complicated :-) ... One table tweet, one table user. A user can post several tweets, Each tweet has only one author. This is `1:n`-related. Now many users can like many tweets. Here you need a mapping table where you can see multiple combinations. Ask for **Which users liked one given tweet?** or ask for **Which tweets did a given user like?** This needs `m:n`-relation...

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev I think, I know now where you turn wrong: I think you are mixing the author of a tweet with the liking users. Although they both are coming from the user-table, the author is *side-data* of a tweet while a liking user has his own relation to the tweet.

Comment: I understood the part `user - favorites - tweets`. The table `favorites` serves as a middle table between `users` and `tweets`. One user can like many tweets, and the same tweet can be liked by many users. But what kind of the relationship do `users` and `connection` have? I looks like it's a one-to-many (one user can have many followers). But I'm not sure because a follower is a user himself. I inserted my database schema to the original question.

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev Your schema looks alright... It is very difficult to understand relations if the the related entities are coming from the same table. One user can follow many other users and can be followed by many other users, This is a `m:n`-relation. *But how should there be a table **in the middle** when there is the same table to left and to the right?* If my answer solves your question, it would be nice to accept and upvote it, thx!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133883/discussion-between-maksim-dmitriev-and-shnugo).